# Trying to fade in a div on load

Tags: jquery, html, class, load, fade

I want to fade in all divs of a certain class when they are fully loaded. I wonder why this isn't working? Surely it must be some of the simplest jQuery possible. I checked the console, and it seems like the .load never fires.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  

        console.log("FIRING");
$( '.back-image').load(function() {
     $(this).fadeIn('slow'); 
        console.log("FADING");
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fading out, as the title says, is not the same as fading in, as your code states.
Also, the `load` method does not do what you think it does; you want to completely rid of `.load(function() {
     $(this)` (and the matching parenthesis `});`) to have the items of class `back-image` fading in.

Also, you'll want to make sure they're not visible to begin with, otherwise the script will have a hard time showing any effect.

Comment: sorry for the typo in the title, my brain is so toast right now :)

I'd basically like the divs to wait with fading in until the background images for said divs are loaded. That's why I thought .load() was the right thing to use. Any solutions not obvious to my newbie mind?

Comment: What I wrote, removing the `.load()` part, should solve your issue.

Comment: I'd leave you alone if it would do that. However, when i open the page only the first div fades in properly, while the others just load jerkily down the page (what I'm trying to avoid). Oh well...

Comment: Then I guess it's back to your original code, substituting `load` with `ready`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that load is an ajax function. You are requesting your image to load from an outside page that you don't provide.  I'm guessing you want to load this image from the page you are on, so .load() is not the function to use in this case.

For more info check out the [jQuery API for .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Did you try doing this?

```
$('.backimage').fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: I guess I was a bit unclear: I'd like to wait until the background images for my divs are loaded before showing them - or else they'll render jerkily and look silly :)

That code doesn't let them fire one by one, or am i missing something?

Comment: If you want them to fire one at a time use the .each() function jquery provides.

For example 
var images = $('.backimage');
images.each(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});